# How to set background color in vaadin text area

Tags: textarea, vaadin, styling

I am trying to customize the appearance of text areas by setting a css style as follows in my own theme:

```
textarea.v-textarea {
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
    background-color:black;
    color: light green;  
}
```

This works fine when the TextArea does not have the focus (i.e. text is green and background is black). The moment I click in the TextArea, the background switches back to white...what am i missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override other styles by adding `!important` to the style

```
textarea.v-textarea {
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
    background-color:black !important;
    color: light green;  
}
```

I would also search all the css and see if somewhere there is something like this and remove it

```
textarea.v-textarea::selection {
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
    background-color:white;
    color: light green;  
}
```